# Matplotlib 3D pan and zoom not working

Tags: matplotlib, mplot3d

When i try to use the pan and zoom tool, the plot rotates on left click and zooms from the center on right click. zooming the plot by making a rectangular selection is not working.
Has somebody a clue how this problem can be solved?

Answer (score 3):

Looking through the source code on github, it doesn't appear that the features you are looking for are supported. Hence you are unable to zoom and/or pan using `mplot3d.Axes3D`

```
def can_zoom(self) :
"""
Return *True* if this axes supports the zoom box button functionality.
3D axes objects do not use the zoom box button.
"""
return False

def can_pan(self) :
"""
Return *True* if this axes supports the pan/zoom button functionality.
3D axes objects do not use the pan/zoom button.
"""
return False
```

Source code: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py
At the time of writing these are on lines 1017 through to 1031